# open a URL in Discord using JDA?

Tags: discord-jda

I am using the JDA API for Java Discord bots. When a user click on a button, it should open a url. But I don't know how to do this. Can someone help me?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need a SlashListener for create a Message with a button. This script looks to see if someone types /sendLink and then sends back a button

```
public class SlashListener extends ListenerAdapter {
   public void onSlashCommand(SlashCommandEvent event) {
       if (event.getName().equals("sendLink")) {
           event.reply("Click the button to open Link")
               .addActionRow( 
                   Button.link("https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA", "GitHub").queue();
       }
   }
 }
```

But remember to register the SlashCommand and the Listener in the MainClass

Comment: For a more detailed documentation look here [JDA documentation](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/interactions/components/Button.html)